# How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case

How do I perform an `IF...THEN` in an `SQL SELECT` statement?

For example:

```
SELECT IF(Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y' ? 1 : 0) AS Saleable, * FROM Product
```

Answer (score 2041, accepted):

The `CASE` statement is the closest to IF in SQL and is supported on all versions of SQL Server.

```
SELECT CAST(
             CASE
                  WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'
                     THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
             END AS bit) as Saleable, *
FROM Product
```

You only need to use the `CAST` operator if you want the result as a Boolean value. If you are happy with an `int`, this works:

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
       END as Saleable, *
FROM Product
```

`CASE` statements can be embedded in other `CASE` statements and even included in aggregates.

SQL Server Denali (SQL Server 2012) adds the [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) statement which is also available in [access](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) (pointed out by [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select/6769805#6769805)):

```
SELECT IIF(Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y', 1, 0) as Saleable, * FROM Product
```

Comment: Beware of dirty secrets of CASE/IIF: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Comment: I implemented this on a SQLite3 database, following this tutorial: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-iif/

Answer (score 369):

The case statement is your friend in this situation, and takes one of two forms:

The simple case:

```
SELECT CASE <variable> WHEN <value>      THEN <returnvalue>
                       WHEN <othervalue> THEN <returnthis>
                                         ELSE <returndefaultcase>
       END AS <newcolumnname>
FROM <table>
```

The extended case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <test>      THEN <returnvalue>
            WHEN <othertest> THEN <returnthis>
                             ELSE <returndefaultcase>
       END AS <newcolumnname>
FROM <table>
```

You can even put case statements in an order by clause for really fancy ordering.

Answer (score 320):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use the [**`IIF`** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx) for this.

```
SELECT IIF(Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y', 1, 0) AS Salable, *
FROM   Product
```

This is effectively just a shorthand (albeit not standard SQL) way of writing `CASE`.

I prefer the conciseness when compared with the expanded `CASE` version.

Both `IIF()` and `CASE` resolve as expressions within a SQL statement and can only be used in well-defined places.

> The CASE expression cannot be used to control the flow of execution of
>   Transact-SQL statements, statement blocks, user-defined functions, and
>   stored procedures.

If your needs can not be satisfied by these limitations (for example, a need to return differently shaped result sets dependent on some condition) then SQL Server does also have a procedural [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182717.aspx) keyword.

```
IF @IncludeExtendedInformation = 1
  BEGIN
      SELECT A,B,C,X,Y,Z
      FROM   T
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SELECT A,B,C
      FROM   T
  END
```

[Care must sometimes be taken to avoid parameter sniffing issues with this approach however](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9874/3690).

Answer (score 115):

You can find some nice examples in *[The Power of SQL CASE Statements](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728081626/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/102704-1.shtml)*, and I think the statement that you can use will be something like this (from [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com)):

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    CASE Gender
        WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
    END
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 87):

Use CASE.  Something like this.

```
SELECT Salable =
        CASE Obsolete
        WHEN 'N' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Answer (score 63):

```
SELECT  
(CASE 
     WHEN (Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y') THEN 'YES'
                                            ELSE 'NO' 
 END) as Salable
, * 
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 52):

```
 SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN OBSOLETE = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' THEN 'TRUE' 
      ELSE 'FALSE' 
   END AS Salable,
   * 
FROM PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 52):

From [this link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3087431/T-SQL-Programming-Part-1---Defining-Variables-and-IFELSE-logic.htm), we can understand `IF THEN ELSE` in T-SQL:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   Northwind.dbo.Customers
          WHERE  CustomerId = 'ALFKI')
  PRINT 'Need to update Customer Record ALFKI'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Need to add Customer Record ALFKI'

IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   Northwind.dbo.Customers
          WHERE  CustomerId = 'LARSE')
  PRINT 'Need to update Customer Record LARSE'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Need to add Customer Record LARSE'
```

Isn't this good enough for T-SQL?

Comment: This isn't what the requester wanted, but is very useful to know that you can use if statements *outside* a select statement.

Comment: EXISTS is good because it kicks out of the search loop if item is found. A COUNT runs until the end of table rows. Nothing to do with question, but something to know.

Answer (score 51):

Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL)

In a `select`, use:

```
select case when Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' then 'YES' else 'NO' end
```

In a `where` clause, use:

```
where 1 = case when Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just do `where Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'` and cut the where in half practically

Answer (score 34):

Simple if-else statement in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @val INT;
SET @val = 15;

IF @val < 25
PRINT 'Hi Ravi Anand';
ELSE
PRINT 'By Ravi Anand.';

GO
```

Nested If...else statement in SQL Server -

```
DECLARE @val INT;
SET @val = 15;

IF @val < 25
PRINT 'Hi Ravi Anand.';
ELSE
BEGIN
IF @val < 50
  PRINT 'what''s up?';
ELSE
  PRINT 'Bye Ravi Anand.';
END;

GO
```

Comment: Late but is it usable inside `SELECT` as OP asked?

Answer (score 25):

Use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN (Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y')
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
END as Available

etc...
```

Answer (score 24):

A new feature, [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx) (that we can simply use), was added in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT IIF ( (Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y'), 1, 0) AS Saleable, * FROM Product
```

Comment: This answer repeats (with less detail) what was [already provided in the answer by Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769805/4515489) several years ago.

Comment: @jk7 this was the first answer to the question .

Comment: Not from what I see.  It says your answer was posted Apr 26 '16 and Martin's was posted Jul 20 '11.

Answer (score 23):

Use pure bit logic:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL
   ,Obsolote CHAR(1)
   ,Instock CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @Product ([Obsolote], [Instock])
    VALUES ('N', 'N'), ('N', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Y'), ('Y', 'N')

;
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT
        'CheckIfInstock' = CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(p.[Instock], 'Y'), 1), 'N'), 0) AS BIT)
       ,'CheckIfObsolote' = CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(p.[Obsolote], 'N'), 0), 'Y'), 1) AS BIT)
       ,*
    FROM
        @Product AS p
)
SELECT
    'Salable' = c.[CheckIfInstock] & ~c.[CheckIfObsolote]
   ,*
FROM
    [cte] c
```

See [working demo: if then without `case` in SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b900/3/0).

For start, you need to work out the value of `true` and `false` for selected conditions. Here comes two [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
for true: ISNULL(NULLIF(p.[Instock], 'Y'), 1)
for false: ISNULL(NULLIF(p.[Instock], 'N'), 0)
```

combined together gives 1 or 0. Next use [bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx).

It's the most [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) method.

Comment: -1 for Code Obfuscation. Seriously, this is about as far from WYSIWYG as you can get! A ruddy unreadable mess, and if I had to work on your code, I would be cursing all day long... sorry :-/

Comment: @Heliac put cte part in View and you will never see the mess. For long and complicated AND, OR, NOT it it more readable than CASE (that part outside cte of course).

Comment: I've given this a +1 for the neatness, once it's in a cte, but note that the answer is currently wrong for the question. You need an '|' not an '&'.

Comment: Totally agree with @Heliac. While it is syntactically correct and works fine it is just not easily supportable. Putting it in a CTE will just move that piece of un-readable code somewhere else.

Comment: The table method of checking combination could have its advantages. Using a table variable and joining it to the existing query could provide a set-based solution without a case. This answer is a poor example, but the table idea itself has merit.

Comment: `NULLIF` link from Microsoft is expired. here is new working link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   Updated in answer.

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT 1 AS Saleable, *
  FROM @Product
 WHERE ( Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y' )
UNION
SELECT 0 AS Saleable, *
  FROM @Product
 WHERE NOT ( Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y' )
```

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN profile.nrefillno = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'R'END as newref
From profile
```

Answer (score 13):

```
case statement some what similar to if in SQL server

SELECT CASE 
            WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
       END as Saleable, * 
FROM Product
```

Comment: Could you please put some explanation on how this answers the question asked?

Comment: @Guanxi:  though not my answer, a 'case' generalizes an 'if-then-else' (from 2 cases to many)

Answer (score 13):

This isn't an answer, just an example of a CASE statement in use where I work. It has a nested CASE statement. Now you know why my eyes are crossed.

```
 CASE orweb2.dbo.Inventory.RegulatingAgencyName
    WHEN 'Region 1'
        THEN orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactState
    WHEN 'Region 2'
        THEN orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactState
    WHEN 'Region 3'
        THEN orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactState
    WHEN 'DEPT OF AGRICULTURE'
        THEN orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactAg
    ELSE (
            CASE orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.IsContract
                WHEN 1
                    THEN orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactCounty
                ELSE orweb2.dbo.CountyStateAgContactInfo.ContactState
                END
            )
    END AS [County Contact Name]
```

Comment: The edit that reformatted the Case statements is all fine and dandy and makes it more understandable but the SQL would still all lump up in the view that is using it.

Comment: I'm just wandering why `CASE` become upvoted and marked as a answer instead of the `IF` which should have been the answer, like this one, this is still a `CASE`statement, not an `IF`.

Comment: @Mr.J: though not my answer, a 'case' generalizes an 'if-then-else' (from 2 cases to many)

Answer (score 10):

If you're inserting results into a table for the first time, rather than transferring results from one table to another, this works in [Oracle 11.2g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Releases_and_versions):

```
INSERT INTO customers (last_name, first_name, city)
    SELECT 'Doe', 'John', 'Chicago' FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT '1' from customers
            where last_name = 'Doe'
            and first_name = 'John'
            and city = 'Chicago');
```

Comment: the tags say SQL Server, TSQL

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative solution to the `CASE` statement, a table-driven approach can be used:

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE (ID INT, Obsolete VARCHAR(10), InStock VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES
(1,'N','Y'),
(2,'A','B'),
(3,'N','B'),
(4,'A','Y')

SELECT P.* , ISNULL(Stmt.Saleable,0) Saleable
FROM
    @Product P
    LEFT JOIN
        ( VALUES
            ( 'N', 'Y', 1 )
        ) Stmt (Obsolete, InStock, Saleable)
        ON  P.InStock = Stmt.InStock OR P.Obsolete = Stmt.Obsolete
```

Result:

```
ID          Obsolete   InStock    Saleable
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1           N          Y          1
2           A          B          0
3           N          B          1
4           A          Y          1
```

Comment: Saleable is used in where condition in query?

Comment: It can be use in where condition.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
             END AS Saleable, * 
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 8):

You can have two choices for this to actually implement:

1. Using IIF, which got introduced from SQL Server 2012:

   ```
   SELECT IIF ( (Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y'), 1, 0) AS Saleable, * FROM Product
   ```
2. Using `Select Case`:

   ```
   SELECT CASE
       WHEN Obsolete = 'N' or InStock = 'Y'
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END as Saleable, *
       FROM Product
   ```

Answer (score 8):

Using SQL CASE is just like normal If / Else statements.
In the below query, if obsolete value = 'N' or if InStock value = 'Y' then the output will be 1. Otherwise the output will be 0.
Then we put that 0 or 1 value under the Salable Column.

```
SELECT
      CASE
           WHEN obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y'
          THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS Salable
      , *
FROM PRODUCT
```

Comment: It is just like normal If / Else statements. If obsolete value =  'N' or If InStock value = 'Y' Then Output will be 1. Otherwise output will be 0.

Comment: Thank you. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60278997/edit) your post to add this explanation. Like: The `If..Then...Else..` statements usage in `SQL` as follows....

Comment: "Salable"? Isn't it "Saleable"?

Answer (score 5):

Question:

```
SELECT IF(Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y' ? 1 : 0) AS Saleable, * FROM Product
```

ANSI:

```
Select 
  case when p.Obsolete = 'N' 
  or p.InStock = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end as Saleable, 
  p.* 
FROM 
  Product p;
```

Using aliases -- `p` in this case -- will help prevent issues.

Comment: What do you mean by *"ANSI"*? ANSI SQL? What version? 1992? 2011? As opposed what, for example? What was it tested on? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53121744/edit), not here in comments (****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
if((obsolete = 'N' OR instock = 'Y'), 1, 0) AS saleable, *
FROM
product;
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who uses SQL Server 2012, IIF is a feature that has been added and works as an alternative to Case statements.

```
SELECT IIF(Obsolete = 'N' OR InStock = 'Y', 1, 0) AS Salable, *
FROM   Product
```

Comment: This answer repeats (with less detail) what was [already provided in the answer by Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769805/4515489) several years ago.

Answer (score 4):

I like the use of the CASE statements, but the question asked for an IF statement in the SQL Select.  What I've used in the past has been:

```
SELECT

   if(GENDER = "M","Male","Female") as Gender

FROM ...
```

It's like the Excel or sheets IF statements where there is a conditional followed by the true condition and then the false condition:

```
if(condition, true, false)
```

Furthermore, you can nest the *if* statements (but then use should use a CASE :-)

(Note: this works in [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench), but it may not work on other platforms)

Comment: [IF FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) It seems present in MySQL, but not in MSSQL, In MSSQL [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used since version 2012.

Answer (score 3):

It will be something like that:

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN Quantity > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN Quantity = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is under 30"
END AS QuantityText
FROM OrderDetails;
```

Comment: Can we use QuantityText value in where condition in a query ? for example `SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN Quantity > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN Quantity = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is under 30"
END AS QuantityText
FROM OrderDetails WHERE QuantityText = 'The quantity is 30'; `

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, I would add that SQL uses three-valued logic. The expression:

```
obsolete = 'N' OR instock = 'Y'
```

Could produce three distinct results:

```
| obsolete | instock | saleable |
|----------|---------|----------|
| Y        | Y       | true     |
| Y        | N       | false    |
| Y        | null    | null     |
| N        | Y       | true     |
| N        | N       | true     |
| N        | null    | true     |
| null     | Y       | true     |
| null     | N       | null     |
| null     | null    | null     |
```

So for example if a product is obsolete but you dont know if product is instock then you dont know if product is saleable. You can write this three-valued logic as follows:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN obsolete = 'N' OR instock = 'Y' THEN 'true'
           WHEN NOT (obsolete = 'N' OR instock = 'Y') THEN 'false'
           ELSE NULL
       END AS saleable
```

Once you figure out how it works, you can convert three results to two results by deciding the behavior of null. E.g. this would treat null as not saleable:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN obsolete = 'N' OR instock = 'Y' THEN 'true'
           ELSE 'false' -- either false or null
       END AS saleable
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple conditions.

```
SELECT

(CASE
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1001' THEN 'DM'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1002' THEN 'GS'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1003' THEN 'MB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1004' THEN 'MP'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1005' THEN 'PL'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1008' THEN 'DM-27'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1011' THEN 'PB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1012' THEN 'UT-2'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1013' THEN 'JGC'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1014' THEN 'SB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1015' THEN 'IR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1016' THEN 'UT-3'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1017' THEN 'UT-4'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1019' THEN 'KR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1020' THEN 'SYB-SB'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1021' THEN 'GR'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1022' THEN 'SYB-KP'
WHEN RIGHT((LEFT(POSID,5)),4) LIKE '1026' THEN 'BNS'

  ELSE ''
END) AS OUTLET

FROM matrixcrm.Transact
```

Comment: Why 18? Why not 19? What do all the magic numbers and letter codes mean? For instance, what is "SYB-KP"? Why all the redundancy? An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71934110/edit), not here in comments (********** ***without*** ************ "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an old question, however if I understood your question and thought correctly, you want to implement the if/else conditional statement in SQL. Both are calculated as a separate column.

The `iif()` function was introduced in 2012, however let's understand the difference between `case` and `iif()` statements. If you need to write just one condition, then `iif()` is sufficient, however if you want to write multiple `iif()` conditions within one statement then you will have to use `case' statement as demonstrated in above responses. Here is an example for your reference.

```
   `select 
    s.name,s.mrn, 
    s.specialtyshort,
    s.admissiondate, 
    s.dischargedate,
    iif(s.admissiondate is not null, 'linked','notlinked') as s.admissionStatus 
    from specialty s`
```

Now if you need to include any other filter or condition in the above statement, you will need to write another `iif()` statement. On the other hand, `case` expression can include multiple conditions within one expression. Do some research on the difference between a `case` statement and `case` expression. The below is a `case` expression that evaluates to a value.

```
`select
 t.name 
,t.MRID
,t.operationDate
,t.dischargeDate
,case 
     when t.specialty like '%obstetrics%' then 'OBS'
     when t.specialty like '%orthopaedics%' then 'ORT'
     when t.specialty like '%General Surgery%' then 'GEN'
     when t.specialty like '%Cardiology%' then 'CAR'
else 'not available' --evaluates to a value.
end as derived_specialty

from 
OperationsTables t`
```