# SQL - get the article title with the last comment date

Tags: sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have articles table, article_comments.

I want to get the value: last_modified_all of article. I need this value to be the great date of this two:

1. the last_modified field of articles table.
2. the last comment of article_comments last_modified column.

Can someone help me? the structure is very simple, and you can guess is without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the greatest-n-per-group problem that comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.  Here's how I solve it:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.last_modified, c1.last_modified AS last_comment_date
FROM articles AS a
JOIN article_comments AS c1
 ON (a.article_id = c2.article_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments AS c2
 ON (a.article_id = c2.article_id AND c1.last_modified < c2.last_modified)
WHERE c2.article_id IS NULL;
```

This has a chance of producing more than one row per article unless `article_comments.last_modified` is unique.  To resolve this, use a tiebreaker.  For instance, if there's an auto-incrementing primary key column:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.last_modified, c1.last_modified AS last_comment_date
FROM articles AS a
JOIN article_comments AS c1
 ON (a.article_id = c2.article_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments AS c2
 ON (a.article_id = c2.article_id AND (c1.last_modified < c2.last_modified
     OR c1.last_modified = c2.last_modified AND c1.comment_id < c2.comment_id))
WHERE c2.article_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it with `OUTER APPLY`. How can I get the latest date of two dates in sql server query?

Comment: +1, but what is the N in "greatest-n-per-group"?  I thought the problem was called "select records holding groupwise maximum" :)

Comment: I want to show only the `LastDateOf(a.last_modified, c1.last_modified AS last_comment_date) as last_modified_all`

Comment: This was helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-a-sql-select

Comment: @Andomar: In this case, N is 1.  In some variations on the question, people may ask for most recent three per article, or something else.  And of course *least* can sometimes be substituted for *greatest*.  But the tag that has been coined on Stack Overflow is `greatest-n-per-group` which is close enough.

Comment: `article_comments AS c1 ON ( a.article_id = c2.article_id )` looks like it should be `article_comments AS c1 ON ( a.article_id = c1.article_id )`

Comment: @YuriKolovsky, you are correct.  Feel free to edit it.  I've stopped posting to StackOverflow (except to respond to comments).