# SQL - Default Value based on a if command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with one String column.
I want to insert another column null that the value of the lines already inserted on the DB will be filled with a "y" or "n" based if the String column is filled or not.
Is it possible to do?

actually it won't have a default value. i just need to know if is possible to set these values based on a if command

Comment: I _think_ I understand what you mean, but could you maybe edit your post with an example with two or three rows before and after this transformation?

Comment: Is the other column already populated? Do you want to insert values for new columns as they come in? Why do you need to add a column for a calculated value like this?

Comment: its running like this in production, I want to switch it, but don't want to have null pointers or anything like that, do you knopw what i mean?

Comment: calculating this with a select query rather than adding a column would be preferable. You can make a view from the select query if you need tabular representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE
        mytable
ADD     is_string_filled AS (CASE WHEN string_field IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END)
```

Comment: how can I add a column after another column
for example, i want to insert column 3 between columns 1 and 2

Comment: @Pringlesinn - you can't without remaking the table.  It's not important since you can say `SELECT col2, col3, col1` to change the order.

Comment: @pringlesinn: you can't. But you can just change the column order in the query (and in fact just do this calculation in the query).

Comment: The column order should not be important. @JNK +1 for that comment

Answer (score 3):

```
//You can implement this in a select query as well instead of adding a column.
select strColumn, 
CASE 
    WHEN strColumn is null THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
END as colCheck

FROM TABLE1;
```

You can know more about using conditional clause in sql out here : [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-a-sql-select)

Calculating the above problem with a slect query rather than adding a column would be preferable. You can make a view from the select query if you need tabular representation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Computed Columns ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx