# Using case when - Is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Right off the bat - I'm quite new to 'case when'. I read the following: [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select) however it didn't really answer my question.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is something along the lines of the following:

```
select
    section_name, *
from
    property.lease_period lp
where
    lp.lease_current_stop_date < getdate() and (lp.lease_status = 'Active' or lp.lease_status = 'Overholding')
    and lp.period_id = @period_id
    and lp.building_id = @building_id
    and not exists
    (
        select 1
        from lease_deal.lease
        where lp.suite_name = tenancy_reference
        and lp.building_id = building_id
    )
    case when(@section_name <> 'ALL')
    then(and upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name))
    end
order by period_id desc
```

Is this possible? If so what am I doing wrong?

**Tl;dr:**

Essentially I would like:

```
and upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name)
```

To only apply to my where clause when @section_name is not equal to 'ALL'

Comment: Do not ever use select *. Here you would be returning section_name twice which is wasteful of server resources. Same thing happens if you have a join. Plus select * by itself is slower. Use only the columns you actually need.

Comment: I agree however this SQL is being used for an SSRS report - My normal point of call there is to start off with selecting all columns and then change the query to be more specific once I know everything that the report will be using (clients often request additional data to be added throughout the development process).

I do concede that I should have used lp.* here though - declaring * itself is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can change your (non-working) CASE to

```
AND (@section_name = 'ALL' OR upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name))
```

Comment: And if your server is not CASE-censitive - you can just skip the UPPER functions to gain more performance and to use (may be) proper index

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a simpler way without the need to use CASE. It will be something like this:

```
and ((upper(section_name) = upper(@section_name) and @section_name <> 'ALL') OR @section_name ='ALL')
```

Comment: Excellent! For interests sake is there a way to accomplish what I outlined above with a case?

Answer (score 0):

```
AND upper(section_name)=CASE WHEN @section_name <> 'ALL' THEN upper(@section_name)
                                                         ELSE upper(section_name)
                        END
```