# Looking to print custom message from Select query at MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I am trying print a vaules retrived from select but, I could not find the way in MSSQL.

I mean I have query

```
select str_id,value from board (this is a simplify query, the one has several joins)
```

this show

```
CIM.MotherID,0xfffffff
CIM.MotherID,0x1234234
```

I would like something like to get

```
Mother ID, Oxffffff
Mother ID, Ox123213
```

I tried with IF statement but I could not get it Do you have any clue?

Comment: do some string operation on 1st column..

Comment: Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258891(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select STUFF(SUBSTRING(str_id,5,12),6,7,' '),value from board (this is a simplify query, the one has several joins)
```

Comment: thank you, i have 3 different possible return TRIM_Processor.ProcessorId, TRIM_Processor.Name, TRIM_Card.Product, that i need to print as friendly name, since this is to show to not technical staff

Comment: i think the best approach could the explain at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select