# if-else clause in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Is there any way to create query for such request without PL/SQL:

```
if (select count(column) from table = 0)
then select column1, column2, column 3 from table where condition1
else select column1, column2, column 3 from table where condition2
```

Comment: Are you selecting from the same table called `table` in all three `select`s?

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2, column3 
  from table 
 where (condition1 and (select count(column) from table) = 0)
    or (condition2 and (select count(column) from table) != 0)
```

Comment: `exists (select column from table)` is usually more efficient than `(select count(column) from table) = 0`

Comment: @ypercube That "exists" would always be true if there were any rows in the table at all, regardless of column being null or not. You'd want "exists (select null from table where column is not null)"

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = SELECT QUERY;

if(Column != 0)
{
     SELECT QUERY;
}
if(Column2 != 0)
{
     SELECT QUERY;
}
```

It should work when you don't add an else statement.

Comment: According to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870009/if-else-statement-in-sql'

Comment: The OP is asking about re-writing PL/SQL (which is Oracle's SQL extension) in plain SQL. The syntax in your answer is *not* PL/SQL (probably TSQL for SQL server?), and it's certainly not plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two LEFT JOINS and COALESCE (here, I use column1 > 2 / column1 <=2 as condition1 and condition2):

```
with 
  v1 as (select count(column4) as c4_cnt from table1),
  v_cond1 as (select column1, column2, column3 from table1 where column1 > 2),
  v_cond2 as (select column1, column2, column3 from table1 where column1 <= 2)
select 
  v1.*, 
  coalesce(v_cond1.column1, v_cond2.column1) as column1,  
  coalesce(v_cond1.column2, v_cond2.column2) as column2,
  coalesce(v_cond1.column3, v_cond2.column3) as column3
from v1
left join v_cond1 on v1.c4_cnt = 0
left join v_cond2 on v1.c4_cnt != 0
```