# SQL SERVER 2005 IF ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am running following query.

```
SELECT T1.C1, T2.C2..., 
IF( T1.C1<>T2.C1,"Changed","1") AS NewColumn
From T1 INNER JOIN T2
Where condition..
```

I am getting syntax error for IF statement.

Motive is to compare columns from two different tables, if not equal save as "Changed" in NewColumn of third table.. This is a `Insert INTO query`.

```
T-> Table
C->Column
```

Comment: SELECT T1.C1, T1.C2, T2.C1, T2.C2.., IF(T1.C3<>T2.C3,"Changed","1") AS NewColumn.... Just to clarify my query..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: You could create a UDF to do an `IIF` (immediate if) function.  Most people (86%) are satisfied with a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.C1, T2.C2..., 
    CASE WHEN T1.C1<>T2.C1 THEN 'Changed' ELSE '1' END AS NewColumn 
From T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON ... 
Where ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use CASE WHEN in this context.

```
SELECT     T1.C1, 
           T2.C2..., 
           CASE WHEN T1.C1<>T2.C1 THEN 'Changed' ELSE '1' END AS NewColumn 
FROM       T1 
INNER JOIN T2 
WHERE      condition
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned that you should use CASE WHEN ELSE END.  The difference between the two is that IF changes the flow of execution of your code - you can conditionally execute code depending on the result of your IF statement.  CASE doesn't change the execution flow - it simply lets you check a value, and then get a different result depending on the result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I got this running using CASE

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use condition checks inside the statement, you should use CASE WHEN

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

But if you have multiline statements, the you can use IF ELSE clause