# IFF Statement error Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement

I come from a MySQL back ground so please bear with me here.  Using MSSQL Server 2008, I am writing a query that has an IFF statement in it.  I get the following error.

```
"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '='."
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    a.[storeno],
    a.[Description],
    a.[transactiondate],
    a.[amount] AS 'pos',
    b.[amount] AS 'ecc',
    a.[amount] - b.[amount] AS 'difference',
    IIF(a.amount = b.amount,'BALANCED','UNBALANCED') AS 'result',
    GETDATE()
FROM
    [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[Txn_Daily_Totals] a
LEFT JOIN
    [POS_REPORT].[dbo].[SAP_FI_INBOUND_DAILY_TOTALS] b ON
    a.[storeno] +
    a.[transactiondate] =
    b.[storeno] +
    b.[transactiondate]
```

I have tried so many different ways and cant get this right.  I have used

```
IF
BEGIN
END
ELSE
END
```

and case.  All give me different errors.  Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 3):

you can write something like this:

```
case when a.amount = b.amount then 'BALANCED' else 'UNBALANCED' end as result
```

instead of

```
IIF(a.amount = b.amount,'BALANCED','UNBALANCED') AS 'result'
```

Answer (score 2):

IIF is not implemented in SQL server 2008. It is a new feature in the 2012 version.