# IF, ELIF, ELSE in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working in SQL Server 2008 and trying to use a `IF, ELIF, ELSE` statement in the `SELECT` section of my code. What I want to do is the following:

```
IF BO.VALUE < BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT
    THEN (BO.VALUE - BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT) #I WANT THIS TO BE NEGATIVE
ELSE IF BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT <= BO.VALUE <= BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT
    THEN BO.VALUE
ELSE
    (BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT - BO.VALUE)
```

The problem is that I do not understand how to do a IF, ELIF, ELSE type transaction in SQL. I have tried to search for this type of example and came across python examples...wrong language so I did a search on the MSDBN site and did not see this sort of work, just IF/ELSE.

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean the 'case' statement?

Comment: `IF-ELSE` in a `SELECT` is not allowed, you probably want `CASE WHEN...ELSE`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think `IF` is allowed in MySQL which makes this more confusing

Comment: [msdn resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want a `CASE` expression.  `CASE` evaluates in order and the first match is what is returned in the query.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN BO.VALUE < BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT 
           THEN (BO.VALUE - BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT)
       WHEN BO.VALUE BETWEEN BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT AND BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT
           THEN BO.VALUE
       ELSE  (BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT - BO.VALUE)
  END as MyColumnAlias
...
```

Comment: is `BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT <= BO.VALUE <= BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT` valid t-sql?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
    col = CASE 
            WHEN BO.VALUE < BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT 
                THEN BO.VALUE - BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT
            WHEN BO.VALUE BETWEEN BO.REFERENCELOWERLIMIT AND BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT 
                THEN BO.VALUE
            ELSE BO.REFERENCEUPPERLIMIT - BO.VALUE
FROM tbl
```