# How to use IF/ELSE in a SELECT - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove the "s" from the word "years" when the COUNT() is < 2 but my syntax is not right for some reason:

**Errors:**
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'.

```
stuff(
        (
        select ',' + Related_name + ' (' + (select
        IF COUNT(begin_date) > 1 BEGIN convert(varchar(10), COUNT(begin_date))  + ' years)' END
        ELSE BEGIN convert(varchar(10), COUNT(begin_date))  + ' year)'
        from cus_relationship subInnerR
        where subInnerR.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
        and subInnerR.related_master_customer_id = innerR.related_master_customer_id
        and subInnerR.relationship_type = 'ADVSPR'
        and subInnerR.relationship_code = 'CLUB'
        and subInnerR.reciprocal_code = 'FACADV')
        from cus_relationship innerR
        where [...]
```

Comment: You can better use case instead of if....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like  this(As commented by gvee in comments as this reduces some repeated code!!):-

```
 select ',' + Related_name + ' (' + (select
    Convert(varchar(10), Count(begin_date)) + ' year' + 
    CASE WHEN Count(begin_date) > 1 THEN 's'    ELSE '' END + ')'
    from cus_relationship subInnerR
    where subInnerR.master_customer_id = c.master_customer_id
    and subInnerR.related_master_customer_id = innerR.related_master_customer_id
    and subInnerR.relationship_type = 'ADVSPR'
    and subInnerR.relationship_code = 'CLUB'
    and subInnerR.reciprocal_code = 'FACADV')
    from cus_relationship innerR
    where [...]
```

Comment: You forgot the `+ ')'` after the `CASE` statement =D

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

In tsql you use `CASE` instead of `IF`

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of reusing the same code, so I'd use [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) like this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COUNT(begin_date)) 
+ ' year' 
+ CASE WHEN COUNT(begin_date) > 1 THEN 's' ELSE '' END
+ ')'
```

*split out on multiple lines for readability*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this with a `CASE` statement instead of `IF`:

```
case
    when COUNT(begin_date) > 1 then
        convert(varchar(10), COUNT(begin_date))  + ' years)'
    else
        convert(varchar(10), COUNT(begin_date))  + ' year)'
end
```

Comment: Quick thought to reduce repeated code: `Convert(varchar(10), Count(begin_date)) + ' year' + CASE WHEN Count(begin_date) > 1 THEN 's' ELSE '' END`