# Hibernate: How can I select max column value which returns 0 and null based on condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, select, aggregate-functions

How can I select max column value which returns `0` when no rows matching condition and returns `null` when any row contains the column with `null` value

For example:

```
SELECT MAX(groupId) from Interview WHERE appId= 61
```

When no rows present matching this condition or when there are rows with `groupId=null`, it returns 
`0` - when `queryForInt()`, `null` - when `queryForList()` and get the first entry.

Please let me know, either query change or Hibernate method.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts your second sentence. Maybe you should be thinking about two queries.  Or a general query and handle the "business logic" in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

SELECT CASE MaxGroupId WHEN COUNT(groupId)=0      THEN 0
                       ELSE MAX(groupId)
       END
FROM Interview
WHERE appId=61

SQL If statement help:[How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Or Something like:

SELECT CASE MaxGroupId WHEN COUNT(Record_id)=0      THEN 0
                       ELSE MAX(groupId)
       END
FROM Interview
WHERE appId=61 AND Group by ANOTHERCOLUMN

Comment: The problem is that count(groupId) is always returns 0 even when no rows matching and when groupId is null.
Anyway thanks for your suggestions. For now I have handled the use case in my code.
Thanks all

Comment: You could use some other column to count on.  What other columns are there in your interview table. Is there a non-nll primary key like record id? You could use that.

Comment: Awesome. It works perfectly..Huge thanks...   



select CASE  WHEN COUNT(id)=0 THEN 0 ELSE MAX(groupId) END as maxGroupId FROM Interview 
WHERE applicationId=61