# Is this a good scenario for MSSQL CASE statement?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm trying to offload some work from the CF server to the SQL Server (2008).

I'm running a query and the statusID value that is returned corresponds to one of 4 colors (Green, Yellow, Orange, and Red).

```
select id, statusID 
from table
```

If this is the ideal situation to use a case statement, is this correct?

```
select id,  
    case  
        when statusid in (1,20,24)  
            then 'red'
    END as xxxx) as yyyy, *
from TABLE
```

And if this is correct, what goes into xxxx and yyyy above?

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select but I'm not sure how to translate that example to my scenario.

Comment: I would consider returning a CSS class name that is descriptive. Something like `Error,Warning,Caution,OK`. That way if you ever have to change a color, it is via CSS rather than SQL

Comment: Up-voting just for this: "I'm trying to offload some work from the CF server to the SQL Server (2008)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close with the syntax, although you'd only want a maximum of one `AS` to give the column a name, so you could have something like this (of course, I've dreamt up values to illustrate options):

```
SELECT      id,  
            CASE 
                WHEN statusid IN (1,20,24) THEN 'red'
                WHEN statusid IN (2,30,34) THEN 'yellow'
                WHEN statusid 8 THEN 'orange'
                WHEN statusid > 35 THEN 'green'
                ELSE 'unrecognised'
            END AS ColorName,
            statusid

FROM        dbo.table
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thank you.  I'll approve it when SO says enough time has lapsed.