# Select an ID if count is equal to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query which needs to find an ID number from 3 WHERE values based on the result only being equal to 1.

So say i want to find a patient's `ID` and my where clause matches the `firstname`, `lastname` and `DOB`. If there are 2 results because of duplicates, i need the output to be NIL else it should return the patient ID.

```
if(select count(*)
from patient
where last_name = 'JAMES' 
and first_name = 'JONES' 
and birth_DtTM = '1980-01-01') > 1
print 'NULL' else return Pat_ID1
```

This is kind of what i am leading towards.

Thanks guys

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select

Comment: @nathvarun disagree, because using a case expression and a subselect is probably *not* a good solution to this problem even if it's what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when  count(*)> 1
then 'NULL' else Pat_ID1 end 
from patient
where last_name = 'JAMES' 
and first_name = 'JONES' 
and birth_DtTM = '1980-01-01'
group by Pat_ID1
```

Answer (score 0):

try below.

```
;WITH CTE(Pat_ID1,last_name,first_name,birth_DtTM,dup_rows)
as
(
    SELECT Pat_ID1,last_name,first_name,birth_DtTM,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY last_name,first_name,birth_DtTM ORDER BY Pat_ID1) AS dup_rows FROM patient
)
SELECT 
case when dup_rows>1 then null
            when dup_rows=1 then Pat_ID1
            end
 FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  PatientID = CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(Pat_ID1) END
FROM
  patient
WHERE
  last_name = 'JAMES' 
  AND first_name = 'JONES' 
  AND birth_DtTM = '1980-01-01'
;
```

The CASE expression will evaluate either to the single `Pat_ID1` matching the request or to NULL (if `COUNT(*)` is anything but 1).

As you can see, the `Pat_ID1` value is obtained with the help of an aggregate function (by the way, you can use MIN instead of MAX just as well). This is because the presence of `COUNT(*)` in the query automatically implies grouping and now, if you want to reference columns of the underlying row set, you must only access their aggregated values.