# IF Condition not working where condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to below query if condition not working

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) as qty 
FROM hud_allotment 
where IF (dvn_cd='$q') and IF(to_dvn='$q');
```

please advise me

Comment: Hi try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why `IF`? Why cant you give like `SELECT SUM(quantity) as qty FROM hud_allotment where dvn_cd='$q' and to_dvn='$q';`

Comment: the dvn_cd or to_dvn any one value come so only i am asking if condition

Answer (score 0):

You do not need if it could be done with `where and`

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) as qty 
FROM hud_allotment 
where dvn_cd='$q' and to_dvn='$q';
```

Comment: the dvn_cd or to_dvn any one value come so only i am asking if condition

Comment: Then change the condition to `where where dvn_cd='$q' or to_dvn='$q';  `
Better if you provide some sample data and expected output it would be better to understand.