# Code for IF…THEN in SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a SQL newbie, in that case, I want to perform an IF..THEN in SQL SELECT statement, I try to write code like this, but it returns an error syntax

Here's my code :

```
SELECT *,IF(total_skor <= 100 AND total_skor >= 80,"Amat Baik")
AS pred FROM rekap_nilai ORDER BY id ASC
```

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code? Thanks sir/madam.

Comment: Ya prob wanna goggle `mysql case when`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing else part in your query otherwise your query ok.Below query with else part.

```
SELECT *,IF(total_skor <= 100 AND total_skor >= 80,"Amat Baik",NULL) AS pred FROM rekap_nilai ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL `IF` function takes *three* arguments. The first is evaluated as a boolean expression, if it evaluates to true (any non-zero integer value), the function returns the *second* argument, otherwise, it returns the *third* argument.

Your IF is missing a third argument, a value to return when the boolean expression does not evaluate to TRUE.

This can be any expression, including a literal empty string or NULL keyword, whatever you want to return.

```
    IF(total_skor <= 100 AND total_skor >= 80,'Amat Baik','foo')
                                                         ^^^^^^
```

---

NOTES:

Your first argument could also be re-written using a `BETWEEN` comparison, e.g.

```
    IF(total_skor BETWEEN 80 AND 100, 'Amat Baik', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following IF statement

```
SELECT *, IF (total_skor <= 100 AND total_skor >= 80,"AmatBaik",NULL)AS pred 
FROM rekap_nilai 
ORDER BY id ASC
```