# Compare query result on the basis of single column

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:

```
select c_id,'VIP Customer' [Customer Level] from customer where ...
```

union

```
select c_id,'Regular Customer' [Customer Level] from customer where ...
```

if `c_id` is part of first level (VIP) can't be 2nd level(Regular). I am using Union it's not working because second column data is different.

Can someone suggest?

Comment: what you wanna do? a check?

Comment: yes.. I am segmenting customers on basis of some criteria....My resultset for each of level is ready.. Now I am doing check if some c_id is part of first level (VIP) can't be 2nd level(Regular) or some other level below it.

Comment: ok i posted a query you can try, and tell me if is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the error Client query.

```
select A.RC_id
from (
      select c_id RC_id
      from customer
      where 'Regular Customer' criteria) A
inner join (
      select c_id VIP_id
      from customer
      where 'VIP Customer' criteria) B
on A.RC_id=B.VIP_id
```

or you can apply both criteria on the Client, i think is the shortest solution

```
select c_id
from customer
where ('VIP Customer criteria' AND 'Regular Customer criteria')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly which SQL variant you are using but you may find it helpful to look at the 'case' expression rather than a union, see:

[How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 0):

You could check, if the result-id was included in the first query. So something like this:

```
SELECT c_id,'VIP Customer' [Customer Level] from customer where [CONDITION]
UNION
(select c_id,'Regular Customer' [Customer Level]
from customer where [SECOND_CONDITION] AND
c_id not in 
(SELECT c_id,'VIP Customer' [Customer Level] from customer where [CONDITION]))
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting like ...

1, 'VIP'

1, 'Regular'

?

If so, I'm not sure if the where clause is 100% done yet. If it finds the same customer to be multiple types, that might be a red flag. If the customer is saved as multiple types, then a case statement is probably the way to go in this situation instead of a union.

```
select c_id, case when... then 'VIP' when... then 'Regular' end
```

Answer (score 0):

CASE seems to be a nice solution here, you can add more Customer Levels if needed also.

```
select c_id, [Customer Level] = 
    CASE
        WHEN ... THEN  'VIP Customer'
        ELSE 'Regular Customer'
    END

 from customer
```

More about CASE on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx