# How to using IF Statement in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How to using IF statement in WHERE? Below code doesn't works

```
SELECT item.item_id, 
       item.item_name, 
       item.item_qty 
IF(sell.product_qty IS NULL, item.item_qty, item.item_qty - SUM(sell.product_qty)),
       sell.date_order, 
       sell.date_shipping
FROM item
     OUTER JOIN sell
                ON item.item_id = sell.product_item_id
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN sell.date_order AND sell.date_shipping
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you getting an error? What results are you expecting and what results are you getting?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, but this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select

Comment: Please check [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) for an idea on IF

Comment: @Tot Zam: Error Msg: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CASE statement.

```
CASE WHEN sell.product_qty IS NULL THEN item.item_qty 
ELSE item.item_qty - SUM(sell.product_qty) END
```