# Access query calculation field based on date criteria

Tags: ms-access, database-design

It is my first question at stack overflow. I want to ask if there is any way I could make a field in an Access query which will be based on two other fields? Eg. in the following case, I want to make a field *ReqDate* in the query which will return *DueDate + 1 year* if *products > 90*, and *DueDate + 6 months* if *products < 90*.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB6gm.png)

Answer (score 1):

As this is Access, the query could look like:

```
Select 
    *, 
    DueDate, 
    products, 
    IIf(products > 90, DateAdd("yyyy", 1, DueDate), DateAdd("m", 6, DueDate)) As ReqDate 
From 
    YourTable;
```

or, if you like, a bit tighter:

```
Select 
    *, 
    DueDate, 
    products, 
    DateAdd("m", 6 * (Abs(products > 90) + 1), DueDate) As ReqDate 
From 
    YourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To add date you can use the DATEADD function of sql server.

```
select ID, DueDate, products , 
(CASE 
    WHEN products > 90
        THEN DATEADD(yy, 1, DueDate)
        ELSE DATEADD(mm, 6, DueDate)

END) as ReqDate from table;
```

Links:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

[How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: Not everything is T-SQL.