# JOOQ query for result of boolean expression

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Please suggest JOOQ DSL to query for result of boolean expression
In SQL I would write:

```
SELECT sum(apples.quantity) > sum(bananas.quantity)
FROM ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get a jOOQ `Condition` for your sum comparison, simply write:

```
Condition condition = sum(apples.quantity).gt(sum(bananas.quantity));
```

Now, `Condition` types currently cannot be put into the `SELECT` clause in jOOQ, but you can wrap them using [`DSL.field(Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-):

```
Field<Boolean> field = field(sum(apples.quantity).gt(sum(bananas.quantity)));
```

jOOQ will take care of deciding whether your SQL dialect allows for using predicates as column expressions (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite), or whether this needs to be emulated using an equivalent `CASE` expression (e.g. DB2, HANA, Oracle, SQL Server).

Which leads to:

```
Record1<Boolean> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field(sum(apples.quantity).gt(sum(bananas.quantity))))
   .from(...)
   .fetchOne();
```

Comment: jOOQ is like donuts, is there anything it can't do?  Now a possible improvement would be to have an asField() method on Condition so it would be more discoverable when using an IDE.e.g. sum(apples.quantity).gt(sum(bananas.quantity)).asField()

Comment: @Aner: Indeed, having such a method would be consistent with other API (e.g. `FieldLike.asField()`), but in fact, the `asField()` (and `asTable()`) methods suffer from one big drawback: They cannot be made generic, like the `field()` method shown here.