# Sql - write something instead of NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case

I am doing a query like this:

```
select name, count(*)as num from client, work where client.id = work.idc group by name;
```

And i am getting result of 2 columns, `name` and `num` which i see the name and the sum of how many times each one of the names used something.

I have also clients that did nothing.

What i want to do is showing them also in the new table and instead of writing their count (which is 0 because they still did nothing) i want to write in the same column `num`, "still did nothing".

I heard i can do it with `if` or `case` but i have no clue how.

Comment: What is the point of `where client.id = work.idc`? Could you add a couple of rows as an example?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `CAST`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/63480/2037090

Comment: But that count(*) would never return a 0.

Comment: @Paparazzi, sorry I am new in sql, I don't know for sure but you understood the point. What else I can use instead? I am editing my question only to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a left join to get names with no work
you need count(work.idc) for 0

```
select name
     , case count(work.idc)  when 0  then 'still did nothing' 
                             else cast (count(work.idc) as varchar2 (50)) end  as num
from client  
left join work 
on client.id = work.idc 
group by name;
```

try this

```
select name
     , count(work.idc) as num
from client  
left join work 
on client.id = work.idc 
group by name;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried it but for some reason in the num colums, instead of numbers counted it shows some "blob" string/image, I don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: Wow - try without the case

Comment: but when i am doing the second option you gave without the case i am not getting here the 'still did nothing', only the results not 0.

Comment: i mean, i am getting the 0 but not 'still did nothing' instead of the 0.

Comment: Yes I am aware the second case would return a 0.   I think I have done the hard part and it feels like you are not giving this much effort.

Comment: you are totally right...:) trying the rest by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to change it to a left outer join and do something like this (not sure if syntax is exact for mysql):

```
select 
  name, 
  Case when count(*) =0
       Then 'still did nothing'
       Else cast (count(*) as varchar2 (50))
  End as num
from client left outer join work 
On client.id = work.idc
Group by name;
```

Comment: count(*) will never be 0

Comment: True. Not sure of mysql syntax anyways and looks you corrected it to a left join so that will probably suffice for OP

Answer (score 0):

You can try if or case like this:

```
select name, if (clientWork = 0, 'still did nothing', clientWork) as num from (select name, count(work.idc) as clientWork from client left join work where client.id = work.idc group by name) as Client_Work;
```

or

```
select name, case when clientWork = 0 then 'still did nothing' else clientWork end as num from (select name, count(work.idc) as clientWork from client left join work where client.id = work.idc group by name) as Client_Work;
```

Comment: it returns no answer. in the if the second select returns the answer without the 0 values but then the first select with the if is not working.

Comment: Edited answer with Left Join instead of your Inner Join query.

Comment: Also merged with @Paparazzi's answer.

Comment: now it says error "every derived table must have his own alias" for some reason

Comment: Added alias in answer now. Sorry no MySql Db to test the things, just want to help.