# IF EXISTS in SWITCH statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, switch-statement, exists

I have the following code that doesn't work. What I want to do is based on some variable I have to check if all bit fields of that variable are true. If yes, return true else return false.

Any suggestions?

```
 DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(20);

IF EXISTS (SELECT variable FROM Table1  WHERE IDNO=@IDNO)
BEGIN
   SELECT @var=variable FROM Table1 WHERE IDNO=@IDNO
   SELECT CASE @var 
     WHEN 1 THEN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT CheckFlag FROM Table2  INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.IDNO=Table1.IDNO WHERE [Check1]=1 and [Check2]=1 and [Check3]=1 and Table1.IDNO=@IDNO)
       RETURN 1
      ELSE 
       RETURN 0
     WHEN 2 THEN
      ......
    ELSE -1
END
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "doesn't work" is too vague.   What values do you have in the tables and variables, What are you expecting to happen and what value is currently being returned.

Comment: The error I get is "Incorrect syntax near IF" (line 6). 
Here's the logic of the query:
I have different variables (as in categories) and I want to check some bit fields for each one. If all of the bit fields are true I want the sproc to return true, else the sproc will return false. Based on the input I have to check one @var through switch clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE WHEN` construct requires the `THEN` part to be followed by an [*expression*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx). You cannot put statements there, [such as `IF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select) or `RETURN`.

Instead you should place an expression there, so that when the `SELECT` statement has evaluated it, and has produced its results, you can use *that* value to perform further statements with it, including `IF` or `RETURN`.

So you could replace this:

```
SELECT CASE @var 
    WHEN 1 THEN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT CheckFlag FROM Table2  INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.IDNO=Table1.IDNO WHERE [Check1]=1 and [Check2]=1 and [Check3]=1 and Table1.IDNO=@IDNO)
            RETURN 1
        ELSE 
            RETURN 0
```

with a `RETURN` statement that gets the returned value from the `SELECT`, also using `Count` and `Sign` functions to produce the 0 or 1 value:

```
RETURN SELECT CASE @var 
        WHEN 1 THEN
           (SELECT     Sign(Count(*)) 
            FROM       Table2 
            INNER JOIN Table1 
                    ON Table2.IDNO=Table1.IDNO 
            WHERE      [Check1]=1 and [Check2]=1 and [Check3]=1 and Table1.IDNO=@IDNO)
```