# IF statement within a formula in a SQL query

Tags: sql, if-statement

Let's say I have a table with two numeric columns: NUM and DEN.
I need to extract the ratio NUM/DEN only if DEN isn't 0: otherwise the ratio should be 0.

Something like this:

```
select ID, [...] AS RATIO
from Table
```

where [...] is some kind of equivalent of the excel formula IF(DEN=0;0;NUM/DEN).

Is there a way to perform this kind of query?

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-to-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: `SELECT ISNULL(NUM/NULLIF(DEN, 0), 0)` for Sql Server

Comment: You would have spent way less time, if you actually googled it first.. *downvoted & flagged*

Comment: There are good answers below. If they helped you, could you please mark one as answered? You have asked other questions on SO and haven't accepted answers in the past. I'd highly encourage you to put closure to your questions by marking one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
case
  when DEN = 0 then 0
  else NUM/DEN
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server 2012 you can use : [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx)

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  It has two versions:

```
case [variable]
    when [value1] then [output1]
    when [value2] then [output2]
    when [value3] then [output3]
    ...
    else [outputdefault] end
```

and

```
 case when [Boolean(True/false) expression 1] then [output1]
      when [Boolean(True/false) expression 2] then [output2]
      when [Boolean(True/false) expression 3] then [output3]
    ...
    else [outputdefault] end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you could use `case` statement like w0lf mentioned or you could use `iif` statement like so:

```
select iif(age > 21, 'Allowed', 'Not Allowed') as status
from test;
```

Example:

```
create table test (
  fullname varchar (20),
  age int
);

insert into test values
('John', 10),
('Matt', 90),
('Jane', 25),
('Ruby', 80),
('Randy', null);
```

Result

```
| fullname |      status |
|----------|-------------|
|     John | Not Allowed |
|     Matt |     Allowed |
|     Jane |     Allowed |
|     Ruby |     Allowed |
|    Randy | Not Allowed |
```

The same thing can be written as

```
select case when age > 21 then 'Allowed' else 'Not Allowed' end as status
from test;
```

`case` statement is used by many database engines.

If you are dealing with null and not null values, you could also use `coalesce` like so:

```
select fullname, coalesce(age, 999) as status
from test;
```

The result will be:

```
| fullname | status |
|----------|--------|
|     John |     10 |
|     Matt |     90 |
|     Jane |     25 |
|     Ruby |     80 |
|    Randy |    999 |
```

At first you may think that `coalesce` does `if age is null then 999 else age`. It does that, sort-of, but in particular `coalesce` outputs the first non-null value in a list. So, `coalesce(null, null, 45)` will result in 45. `coalesce(null, 33, 45)` will result in 33.

Feel free to play around with SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a41a7/6