# SQL one select with different where clauses by PHP variable

Tags: php, sql

Unlike [How do I perform an IF…THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447)
, I'm asking about a PHP variable.

I'm trying to create a SQL SELECT statement on my PHP file which can select all person or single person.

```
if ( $watch_person == "all") {
  $sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
            FROM worklist
         ";
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
            FROM worklist
           WHERE PERSON_NO = '".$watch_person."'
         ";
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one SQL statement?

Comment: You are essentially trying to output the same set of data twice. What you can do is grab **all** of the data in a single query, and then filter it in PHP based on the two different sets of **results** that you desire, avoiding the need for a second query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD FROM worklist";
if($watch_person != "all"){
    $sql .= " WHERE PERSON_NO = '$watch_person'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your coding as below.

```
$sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
             FROM worklist WHERE ";
if ( $watch_person == "all") {
   $sql .= " 1=1";
 } else {
   $sql .= "  PERSON_NO = '".$watch_person."' ";
 }
```

**OR**

```
$sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
             FROM worklist WHERE ". ($watch_person == "all" ? "1=1" : "PERSON_NO = '".$watch_person."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the where statement in the if else.

```
$sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
        FROM worklist ". 
        ($watch_person == "all" ? "" : "WHERE PERSON_NO = '".$watch_person."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be more easy to extend where condition.

.

```
$sql = "SELECT WORK_RECORD
             FROM worklist WHERE 1=1 ";

if ( $watch_person != "all") 
   $sql .= "  and PERSON_NO = '".$watch_person."' ";

if ( $watch_person2 != "another") 
   $sql .= "  and example = '".$watch_person2."' ";
```