# How can I make an if and else mysql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to make an if else query in a mysql query. 
Unfortunately I do not know how to do it right.  Can someone please explain?

How can I make a query like this:

```
if s_table.column1 = s_table.column2
set .s_table.column1 = 1
else
set .s_table.column1 = 2
end if
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

I think you are missing the THEN

Can be found on there documentation page : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html