# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

Below is my query where i want to check whether record from TABLE A is being used in TABLE B and based on that i am returning 'Y' and 'N'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.ID,
    IF(da.AM_SYSID IS NULL, 'Y', 'N')
FROM 
    TABLEA ca
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEB da ON ca.ID = da.AM_SYSID
```

but I am getting an error

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound. searched for solution

I'm still unable to see my mistake.

Comment: Did you intend to use `IFF` (rather than `IF`)?

Comment: why i would use that?

Comment: Because `IF` is a statement that you use for control flow, whereas `IFF` is an operator taking a boolean and returning one of two possible results. Since that seems to be what you're trying to do, it looks like you're just using the wrong word here.

Comment: I'd use the ANSI SQL `case` expression instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok..was not aware of this operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your `IF` command.

In SQL Server, `IF` is not a function, ie something that you give two arguments and a condition and it returns the appropriate argument. Instead, it evaluates the condition and *starts running a new statement*. This is not what you want.

The function equivalent is `case`. Thus, what you really want(supposing your query is correct) is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.ID ,
    CASE 
       WHEN da.AM_SYSID IS NULL 
          THEN 'Y' 
          ELSE 'N' 
    END
FROM 
    TABLEA ca
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEB da ON ca.ID = da.AM_SYSID
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in `IF` statement. You need either to use `CASE/WHEN` or `IIF`.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.ID ,
    IIF(da.AM_SYSID IS NULL, 'Y', 'N') AS YourId
FROM 
    TABLEA ca
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEB da ON ca.ID = da.AM_SYSID
```

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63480/2524304

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to write this query is to use `case` and `exists`:

```
SELECT ca.ID,
       (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM TABLEB da 
                              WHERE ca.ID = da.AM_SYSID
                             )
             THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N'
        END)
FROM TABLEA ca;
```

Why is this better?  `SELECT DISTINCT` incurs overhead for removing the duplicates.  This version has no such overhead (assuming that `ca.id` is unique, a reasonable assumption for an `id`).