# SQL query using if else

Tags: sql, if-statement, using

My SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Scores.PupilId, Scores.BoysName, Scores.FormGroup,
    IF (Scores.FormGroup = "10SB", "Great", "ok")
FROM 
    Scores
```

I get this message

> no such function: if: SELECT Scores.PupilId, Scores.BoysName, Scores.FormGroup,
>   if(Scores.FormGroup="10SB","Great","ok")
>   FROM Scores

This is flat file database

Can anyone please help me understand why I am getting a message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 2):

The correct ANSI-standard conditional expression in SQL is the `case` expression:

```
SELECT Scores.PupilId, Scores.BoysName, Scores.FormGroup,  
       (CASE WHEN Scores.FormGroup = '10SB' THEN 'Great' ELSE 'ok' END)
FROM Scores ;
```

Comment: Yes. MS SQL 2012 added an `IIF()` conditional function, but I believe it essentially evaluates out to a `CASE` statement.