# SQL Finding one of two elements in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table *matches* with elements *id* that is PK, *p1_name*, *p2_name*, *p1_score*, *p2_score*.
If I know *id* and name of one of *p's*, how do I found score of this *p*?

Comment: i dont know is my p name first or second, i know only name

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777/3959856

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your *DBMS* tag is `mysql`( formerly `mysql`, `sqlite` existed ), you may use the following syntax with bind variables made up of `case..when` statement :

```
SET @p_id = <myInt>; 
SET @p_name = '<myStringValue>';
select  ( case when `p1_name` = @p_name 
               then `p1_score` 
               else `p2_score`
               end ) as score
  from `matches`
 where `id` = @p_id
   and @p_name in (`p1_name`, `p2_name`);
```

*or*

substiute 
a quoted literal instead for `@p_name` and an integer for `@p_id` as in the [*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/914bf9/3)