# Can I use SQL to display custom text that is based on the column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to show different strings based on value found in a column?

i.e.

```
SELECT value FROM table;

+--------+
| value  |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      0 |
|      1 |
|      1 |
+--------+
```

The output I want is this:

```
+--------+
| value  |
+--------+
|    yes |
|     no |
|    yes |
|    yes |
+--------+
```

How?

Comment: yes, check out case statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fun way to do this uses `elt()`:

```
select elt(value + 1, 'no', 'yes')
```

`elt()` returns the nth string based on the first argument.

Comment: That's pretty neat

Answer (score 7):

Using [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement you can get the expected result:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 'yes' 
            WHEN value = 0 THEN 'no' 
            ELSE '' 
       END AS value
FROM testtable;
```

or using [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) statement

```
SELECT IF(value = 1, 'yes', IF(value = 0, 'no', '')) AS value
FROM testtable;
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2e3bdfc8d5dc5e5efbcc2b4adfab7eb)