# If clause in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare @a varchar(100); 

If @a = select productname from product
```

The above mentioned query is throwing error as my sql query (select product name from product) is returning multiple values.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Do you mean `IN`? What is the expected behaviour here? We don't have enough information. The error is telling you the problem here; you can't compare a scalar value to a dataset containing multiple rows (nor does it make sense to).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: If you are getting multiple products returned, how do you know which one you want to compare with `@a`? How would *you* choose?

Comment: if you had 3 products, 'pan','spoon','knife' - which one do you want and what is in @a - before and after?  What are you wanting to do? - to stop your error you need to select a single product - e.g. If @a = select productname from product where productname = 'pan' print 'I selected the pan';

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Declare @a varchar(100); 
SELECT @a = 'MyProduct'
```

Then either

```
If @a = select TOP 1 productname from product ORDER BY <some field>
```

OR

```
If @a IN (select productname from product)
```

However, how do you know which product(s) to match to; you might need a `WHERE` clause. Some sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, if nothing else. I *suspect* the OP is more likely after an `IN` here. Especially as the subquery has no `WHERE`, so the value returned from the table `product` is always going to be the same (until a "lower" value is added).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the comments, I've update my answer.

Comment: @Larnu Not sure because it's not clear, it may be a `CASE` expression or a`IIF()` function as well.

Comment: @Sami Could be many things - hard to tell without sample data. Thanks for the additional thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you need to put the `SELECT` query inside the parenthesis in this case! Also you should note that your select query, in this case should not return more than one value. So to resolve these you need to write it as:

```
Declare @a varchar(100); 

If @a = (select TOP 1 productname from product)
```

However your query logically seems to be invalid and you should rethink about it, for example you need to say that, you are going to check @a with which product? You might need to add some filters to query and/or add `ELSE` to your if, etc.

You might also need to read the [@PeterSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56769460/1666800)'s answer too(Using `IN`...)