# changing a result

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there is way to select a column but chnage the results depending on their value. For example, if a result is between 1 and 5 to have it show as '1-5'

I have looked online and can only seem to find ways to select only that set of data but I need to keep the whole set of results.

Comment: to give you some background... I am an experienced VBA developer now branching out to SQL

Comment: Please show the data you have, and what data you want to have as result. Also it would be interesting what you've already tried... What DBMS are you using? Your question contains way too less information.

Comment: see [CASE function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)

Comment: Something like: `SELECT CASE WHEN Column BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN '1-5' ELSE ... END`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: @reportgunner: it's a CASE **expression** not a function - another good example why w3fools is not really suited a good resource for SQL.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
select
  case
    when [column_name] between 1 and 5
    then '1-5'
    when [column_name] between 6 and 10
    then '6-10'
    when [column_name] between 11 and 15
    then '11-15'
    else ''
  end as [new_column_name]
  from
    [table_name]
```

Comment: Thats seems to have nailed it! you have a newbie very happy.