# Avoid divide by zero with an IF SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT sum((a.cant*b.cost)/b.cant) AS sum1
FROM
  (SELECT partNo,cant 
    FROM table1 WHERE id=1) AS a,
  (SELECT color,cost,cant 
    FROM table2 WHERE color in 
       (SELECT partNo FROM table1 WHERE id=1)) AS b
WHERE a.partNo=b.color
```

The problem is that sometimes **b.cant** will return **0**, and when I do this part: **SELECT sum((a.cant*b.cost)/b.cant) AS sum1** it will return a divide by zero error message, I was thinking on doing something like this:

```
SELECT IF (b.cant=0,0,sum((a.cant*b.cost)/b.cant)) AS sum1
```

Meaning that if **b.cant** equals zero then I want to return a 0 as final result and stop doing the division, but if it is not equal 0 then I will do the division, in my head this was the solution but is giving me an error.

Is there any other way to avoid doing the division and just return 0 if the divisor is 0?

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: The construction to do that `IF` in SQL is the `CASE` construction.  SELECT CASE WHEN b.cant=0 THEN 0 ELSE sum((a.cant*b.cost)/b.cant) END AS sum1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your `JOIN` syntax and simplify the query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.cant*b.cost) / NULLIF(b.cant, 0) AS sum1
FROM table1 a JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.partNo = b.color AND
        a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

It is rather suspicious that the join condition is between "partno" and "color", but that is how you have phrased it in your query.  I wouldn't be surprised if that were an error.

The answer to your specific question is `NULLIF()`.  But you should also learn how to write clearer SQL code.  In particular, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `JOIN` instead of selecting columns using `select` statement. to avoid `0` you should use `case` expression  as following

```
select
  sum((a.cant*b.cost)/b.can) as sum1
from
(
  select 
    a.partNo,
    a.cant,
    b.color,
    b.cost,
    (case when b.cant = 0 then 1 else b.cant) as b.cant
  from table1 a
  join table2 b
  on a.partNo = b.color
  where a.id = 1
) subq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NULLIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to return `NULL` when `b.cant` is `0`:

```
SUM(a.cant * b.cost / NULLIF(b.cant, 0))
```

If there is a case that the final sum returns `NULL` but you want to see `0` then also use [`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
COALESCE(SUM(a.cant * b.cost / NULLIF(b.cant, 0)), 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

In terms of business, you can judge that `b.cant` equals zero, if `b.cant` equals zero then you can do the default.