# Mysql how to write a query contains where followed by condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing one query, that needs to satisfy the following conditions.

```
select 
    field1, field2, field3
from 
    `tabFirstTable`as ft join 
    `tabSecondTable` as st
where 
    --Upto above its fine but how to turn below logic into query-- 
    IF ft.approval_status in == 'Approved By Manager' and ft.status in ("Created", "Error")
        and //some more conditions
    ELSE ft.approval_status in == 'Approved By HOD' and ft.status in ("Initiated")
        and //some more conditions
```

Because of the above issue currently writing two separate queries, which is not a good idea. Please help.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63447/6309111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something or over simplifying

```
WHERE
    (ft.status IN ('Created', 'Error') AND 
    ft.approval_status = 'Approved By Manager' AND 
        //other stuff
    )
OR 
    (ft.status = 'Initiated' AND 
     ft.approval_status = 'Approved By HOD' AND 
        //some more conditions
    )
```