# How to do IF Condition in Where Clause

Tags: sql, .net, database, where-clause

How can write the below

```
SELECT
    a1.state, b2.name,........* 
FROM
    Table_Name
WHERE
    condition1
    AND condition2
    AND condition3
    AND condition4
    AND IF b2.name = 'mohan' THEN condition 5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `if`.  Just use boolean logic:

```
where condition1 AND
      condition2 AND
      condition3 AND
      condition4 AND
      (b2.name <> 'mohan' OR condition 5)
```