# If function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    order_date,
    IF(YEAR(order_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()), 'active', 'archived') 
FROM 
    orders
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGtlM.png)

Comment: i am just trying to do a  if statement , it can be obtained via case  SELECT order_id as test,
order_date as petcha, 
CASE WHEN  YEAR(order_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'active' ELSE 'archieved' END as testing101 
FROM orders

Comment: You are missing an `I`. `IIF()`

Comment: Looks like you're confusing `MySQL`'s IF to `SQL Server`'s. This should answer your question: [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    order_date,
    CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) THEN "active"
    ELSE "archived"
FROM 
    orders
```