# Compare two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to SQL and have very basic queries in GCP.

Let's consider this table below:

| Name | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arun | 1234-5678 | 1234 |
| Tara | 6789 - 7654 | 6789 |
| Arun | 4567 | 4324 |

Here, I want to compare column B and C and if they match then give 1 else 0 in column `same` and else `different` (which we have to create).

So here the catch:

- if column `B` has `1234-5678` and column `C` has `1234`, then the column should match considering only the number before the "-" in the value.

The output should be :

| Name | B | C | same | different |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arun | 1234-5678 | 1234 | 1 | 0 |
| Tara | 6789 - 7654 | 6789 | 1 | 0 |
| Arun | 4567 | 4324 | 0 | 1 |

Also, I want to count the values of 1 for each values in `Name` for `same` and `different` columns.

So far I've tried this:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    b, 
    c , 
    if(b = c, 1, 0) as same, 
    if (b!=c,1,0) as different, 
    count(same), 
    count(different)
From Table
```

Comment: please specify database you use. Looks like you need to perform string manipulations and the are different in different databases

Comment: @sergey, I'm using GCP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-i-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select)

Comment: For GCP conditional expressions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions

Comment: No, @natrium.. I want to compare the two columns by taking numbers before this "-"

Comment: @Madness just throw in some stringmanipulations (like SUBSTR) to get de stringparts you need, and use that in the case-statement. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions

Comment: Hey @natrium, substring worked. Thanks a lot. Can you help me for other problems that I've mentioned?

Comment: Hi @Madness, what are the other problems ? The number is always 4 characters before the '-' ? You mentionned : "I want to count the values of 1 for each values in Name for 'same' and 'different' column". You want to have the total of 'same' / 'different' per Name ?

Comment: Hey @LPK, yes, per name I want the count of 1's for same and different columns.

Comment: Hey @Madness, I got something but do you need to display the same and different column too ? Or just the total per name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using ***"MySQL"*** (will work almost same with SQL server as well) here's the possible solution.

##### Step 1) Setup table

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    Name varchar(50),
    B varchar(50),
    C varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Users
VALUES
('Arun', '1234-5678', '1234'),
('Tara', '6789-7654', '6789'),
('Arun', '4567', '4324');
```

[image: Users List]

##### Step 2) `same` & `different` columns

```
SELECT
    Name, B, C,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as same,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as different
FROM
    Users
```

[image: smae & different query result]

##### Step 3) Join both results to get `total_same` & `total_different` for each user

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_same,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_different
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY Name
```

[image: total same & different for each user]

### Reference: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a503b1/35)

Comment: Hey @talEsid, Can we put this code together in one whole code without creating any new table but just the output table?

Comment: actually this is one whole code. Step 1 & Step 2 are just for reference to show query working. Actual code is the last one which is getting total same & different records

Comment: if you are asking for something else, please elaborate

Comment: okay, got it. Thank you. Just one more question, can I use IF condition in place of CASE? Also, I'm performing this logic on 3-4 tables using left join.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL server?

Comment: I'm updating the query in step 3 with much simpler version, without using joins. Result is exactly same

Comment: I'm using GCP, having join 3-4 tables to my main table using left join.

Comment: Can I also put multiple conditions in case ?

Comment: absolutely. `CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 WHEN 2=2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: thanks a lot, one small question. Can I use or with case?

Answer (score 1):

For the first step, you will need to *SUBSTR* the column b.
We start at position 1 and we want 4 characters (only works if there's only 4 characters before the '-').

```
With table2 as (
  select name, b,c, same, different from (select name, b, c, case when (SUBSTR(b,1,4) = c)
  then '1' else '0' end as same, case when(SUBSTR(b,1,4)!= c) then '1' else '0' end as different
from Table1
group by name, b,c))
```

The WITH clause can be used when you have complex query, and if you want to create a temporary table in order to use it after.

The Table2 give you this :

[image: Output Table2]

After the WITH clause, you will have the second step, the count of same / different per name :

```
Select table1.name,count(table2.same+table2.different) as total from table1 
join table2 on (table2.name = table1.name and table2.b = table1.b)
group by table1.name;
```

The output give you the total per name (the name are group by, so in your example you will only have 2 rows, one for Arun with a total of 2 (same + different) and the other one with a total of 1)

[image: Final Output]

So here's the entire code :

```
with table2 as (
  select name, b,c, same, different from (select name, b, c, case when (SUBSTR(b,1,4) = c) then '1' else '0' end as same, case when(SUBSTR(b,1,4)!= c) then '1' else '0' end as different
From Table1
group by name, b,c))

select table1.name, table1.b, table1.c, count(table2.same+table2.different) as total from table1 
join table2 on (table2.name = table1.name and table2.b = table1.b)
group by table1.name;
```

Comment: Hey @LPK, can we put all this in one code giving one one table? without creating another table?

Comment: Hey Madness, the code from @TalESid will do the trick ! :-)