# Count number of 1's in two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on GCP and I've this table below:

| Name | B | C | same | different |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arun | 1234-5678 | 1234 | 1 | 0 |
| Tara | 6789 - 7654 | 6789 | 1 | 0 |
| Arun | 4567 | 4324 | 0 | 1 |

Here, I have compared `B` and `C` columns by taking the first 4 digits. 
If B and C are same then '1' should come in another column I've created - `Same` 
IF B and C are not same then, '1' should come in another column I've created - `Different`

Now, I want to find the count of same and different for each `Name`.
`If count(same) > 1 then, '1' should come in another column 'YES', which we have to create` 
`If count(different)> 1 then '1' should come in another columns 'NO' else 0 in all cases.`

Basically, For `Arun`, Yes and No columns should come as 1.

So far I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    Name,B, C, 
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as same,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as different,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_same,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_different,
    IF(SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >1) 1, 0 as YES,
    IF(SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >1) 1, 0 as NO
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY Name,B,C
```

Expected output:

| Name | B | C | count(same) | count(different) | yes | no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arun | 1234-5678 | 1234 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Tara | 6789 - 7654 | 6789 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

But it is not working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hey Madness, the answer from your last question didn't helped you ?
What's the output that you need ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966674/compare-two-columns-in-sql)

Comment: @LPK, no It didn't work for count.. that's why posted another question regarding the counts. Please check the output table.

Comment: You can't have the expected output, because you have the name Arun twice with a different B and C column. It comes from the group by, so it will group by name, or group by name, b,c. If you don't put the columns B and C, you will have the good output for the yes and no.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a CTE to define the first table that you have, and then query directly from it and group by `Name`. Like so,

```
WITH subquery AS (
SELECT
    Name,B, C, 
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as same,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(B, "-", 1) <> C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as different
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY Name,B,C
)
SELECT Name, SUM(same) AS total_same, SUM(different) AS total_different
FROM subquery
GROUP BY Name
```

I used `SUM()` as a convenient way to "count 1's" because you explicitly say 1 or 0, so it works.

Comment: Hey Josh, it's basically the same output as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966674/compare-two-columns-in-sql/72967916#72967916
I don't know what @Madness needs... because it will be the same answer as his previous question.

Comment: @LPK no doubt... looks like EXACTLY the same question

Comment: Hey @Josh, thank you for this. If I'm joining 2 tables here so do I need to add prefix in 2nd SELECT statement for name?

Comment: @Madness not quite sure what you mean, but the 2nd SELECT statement is querying the results of the first. But I'm not sure what you mean by joining 2 tables. You're free to change the 1st to join in a way that gives you want you want, or modify the 2nd to join, its up to you and. your problem but I dont think your question has those details for us to say

Comment: I meant to say that if I'm joining two tables here, table1 as t1 and table2 as t2.. Then how will I query for the same problem?